# findViewById is undefined for the type BluetoothLeService

Tags: android, findviewbyid

In my public class BluetoothLeService extends Service, I have the following code:

```
private void updateTimeValues(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    TextView time = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.time);
    time.setText(R.string.time);
```

findViewById is undefined for the type BluetoothLeService. I know that the function is declared in the Activity class but how do I implement the function without extending the Activity class.

I am a novice in Android development so please detail as possible your answer :)

Thanks!

Comment: Service does not have a view. It is a background service that is intended to do long running task behind the scene.

Comment: Are using calling `updateTimeValues ` method from Activity?

Answer (score 2):

That's correct. Service doesn't have ui. From the documentation

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running
>   operations in the background and does not provide a user interface.

you could use a `LocalBroadcastManager` to communicate with the `Activity` whose started the `Service` in order to update the UI

Answer (score 1):

As you will not be able to access the textView directly from the service, you need to create a broadcast receiver in the activity.

In your service, call this onCreate

```
myBroadcast = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
```

Now in your `updateTimeValues()` use myBroadcast:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("myNewBroadcastIntent");
        intent.putExtra("newtime", "//value you want to send");
    myBroadcast.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Now create receiver in the onCreate of your mainActivity as follows:

```
myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String s = intent.getStringExtra("newtime");
        //now you can set it to the textView
    }
};
```

And register it onStart as:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
     .registerReceiver((myReceiver),new IntentFilter("myNewBroadcastIntent"));
```

And unregister onStop as :

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    super.onStop();
```

Hope this helps!